# CSS: background-size: cover; Strange behaviour in Firefox18 - it appends to parent relative positioned element of a parent absolute positioned element

Tags: html, firefox, css

Today I have found a strange behaviour with Firefox 18.0.2.
Even an update to FF19.0 didn't help.

I had the need to create thumbs with a dynamic size keeping a specific aspect ratio.
Possibly there are other better solutions as the following one.

**Html:** - Doctype is HTML5

```
<div class="img">
   <img alt="" src="/blank.gif" class="imgScalar">
   <div class="imgA">
       <div class="imgP">
           <div style="background-image:url(-pathToThumb-)" class="thumb"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The "blank.gif" has a fixed size of 2x2px. It was important to have identical side-length.

**CSS:**

```
.img {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 1px 0;
}
.img .imgScalar {
    width: 100%;
}
.img .imgA {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url('../gfx/loader.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.img .imgP {
    padding: 0 1px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.img .thumb {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.img .imgScalar,
.img.r16-9 .imgScalar {
    margin-bottom: -43.75%;
}
.img.r16-10 .imgScalar {
    margin-bottom: -37.5%;
}
.img.r4-3 .imgScalar {
    margin-bottom: -25%;
}
.img.r9-16 .imgScalar {
    margin-bottom: 77.77777777777777%;
}
.img.r10-16 .imgScalar {
    margin-bottom: 60%;
}
.img.r3-4 .imgScalar {
    margin-bottom: 33.333333333333314%;
}
```

---

The benefit for me is, that I am able to switch the aspect-ratio by CSS when hitting @media rules.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .img.r9-16 .imgScalar,
    .img.r10-16 .imgScalar,
    .img.r3-4 .imgScalar {
        margin-bottom: -25%;
    }
}
```

As information: This is integrated in a layout which is static by default to 1200px width, fluid if the resolution goes below 1200px and the client-browser supports the rules and also reacting on mobile-resolutions - everything CSS only.

I have tested the above with Google Chrome, Opera, Safari, Internet Explorer and on my iPhone and it seems to work on these tested devices ... The only browser that is doing this is Firefox.

**What seems to be the problem:**

Because *.thumb* is a child-element of *.imgA* which is absolut positioned, the background-size seems to be applied to the next relative parent of *.imgA* instead of *.thumb* itself which is also relative positioned. For testing purposes I also made *.imgP* relative but that also doesn't help.

---

**A temporarily solution:**

**Html:**

```
<div class="img">
    <div class="imgWrap">
        <img alt="" src="/iS16-9.gif" style="background-image:url(-imgPath-)" class="imgScalar">
    </div>
</div>
```

iS16-9.gif is one of a couple of blank images which are used as "helper"-elements.
As the name says it has a width of 16px and a height of 9px to represent the aspect ratio.

**CSS:**

```
.img > .imgWrap {
    position: relative;
    margin: 1px;
    background-image: url('../gfx/loader.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.img > .imgWrap > img {
    width: 100%;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

It is too bad that I am now missing the ability to respond to changing resolutions without using javascript-components.

---

Maybe some of you have an idea how to solve this problem?

---

**//EDIT: I checked which browsers are *incompatible* with the first solution:**

- Firefox
- Iceweasel
- Kazehakase 0.5.8
- Iceape
- Seamonkey

There are no problems with any other browser except MSIE5.5 - even MSIE6.0 seems to be able to handle this. Only mozilla-based browsers are totally failing this in all versions (even 20 as I've seen)

Comment: Could you make a sample on jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: never used that before and the load-time is currently really high ... I'll give it a try

Comment: After a 504 Error from jsFiddle i finally got it.
See first solution here @IgorJerosimić: http://jsfiddle.net/Habichtsberg/UW3mG/

Comment: //Edit:
The real funny thing is, that the described problem does not occur in the version posted within JS-Fiddle. I'm trying to find out what the problem is

Comment: I found the solution! - I'll post it tomorrow for everyone who might also be facing a problem like this. Stackoverflow currently disallows me to post an answer within the first 8 hours after writing my question ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours of debugging I've been able to solve the problem by myself.
Thanks to @IgorJerosimic for pushing me to publish a sample at jsfiddle.
After publishing my sample I was able to see, that the code itself does exactly what it should do.

The problem had nothing to do with the way the scaling was done.
In fact it resulted out of the way my css-grid-system behaved on handling columns.
Instead of using float I needed to use inline-block which is a bit tricky - an old fallback to Firefox2.0 resulted the crash.

```
display: inline-block;
display: -moz-inline-grid;
vertical-align: top;
min-height: 1px;
```

After removing the deprecated line **display: -moz-inline-grid;** everything worked fine again. (The code was originally from a german page http://bittersmann.de/articles/inline-block/example9.html)

The first solution is cross-browser compatibel even down to MSIE6.0 (if you add the filter rule for the scale function of the background, otherwise the image is formated in the ratio but not enlarged or reduced).
Admittedly, the amount of code needed is a bit heavy... But so far it is my only solution to make responsive autoscaling image-boxes e.g. for thumb-previews with a fixed ratio and to avoid black stripes around the image.

---

**How to optimize?**

From now on there is the question how to best optimize the code of the first sample to avoid to much traffic. If I compare the two samples there is a difference in size of 26% between the first and the second sample.
At a gallery with 250 thumbnails the first sample would produce an overhead of 12.250 chars.
Calculated upon an UTF-8 charset this would be (if I calculated correctly) 11,9kB of traffic or for slow "DSL" with 30kB downlink a difference of 0.399 seconds per request.

---

Kind regards and hopfully that this might help someone who might be facing this problem,

Dominik Habichtsberg